# Doctrine subquery Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'LIKE'

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem with DQL.
My sql query looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM company c WHERE (SELECT MIN(u.surname) FROM contact u WHERE u.company_id = c.id) LIKE '%a%'
```

I tried to transfer this query in to doctrine:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('XYZBundle:Company')
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('COUNT(c.id)')
            ->where("(SELECT MIN(u.surname) FROM XYZBundle:Contact u where u.id = c.id) LIKE '%a%'")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

but this throw

> QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 136: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'LIKE' '

If i change `LIKE '%a%'` to `= '%a%'` everything work fine but i need LIKE. Why this query does not work?

Comment: you use min() on a varchar ?

Comment: Yes, but as i mentioned the raw SQL work fine, only dql throw exception and i cant get informations :(